# linebreaks not working properly in django

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

My linebreaks are not working when i try to use a custom filter and safe in my web site for publishing post.
html:

```
  <p>{{ text|striptags|linebreaks|mention|safe }}</p>
```

mention is my custom filter and my templatetags is:

```
@register.filter(name='mention',is_safe=True)
@stringfilter
def mention(value):
 res = ""

 for i in value.split():
    if i[0] == '#':
        if len(i[1:]) > 1:
            i = f'<a href="/recommendation/?q=%23{i[1:]}&submit=Search">{i}</a>'


    res = res + i + ' '
return res
```

at the end i am using 'safe' so that the user can see the link.it is working but when i type linebreaks i am not seing the linebreaks inside my html.What am i doing wrong ? do i have problem in ordering my filter ?

Comment: Provide a sample `text` that has issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I’m not sure why you would like to add the `linebreaks` filter. Could you give an example so that I can edit this answer?

Django filters are simple functions you can test directly from a `shell`.

You don’t need to add the `safe` filter after `mention` because you already registered the filter as safe (which is right).

Maybe you want to add the linebreaks at the end of the filter chain, but then in your custom filter, you should split and keep the separator.

Maybe something like:

```py
@register.filter(name='mention',is_safe=True)
@stringfilter
def mention(value):
  res = ''
  parts = re.split('(\s)', value)
  for i, elem in enumerate(parts[::2]):
      if elem and elem[0] == '#' and len(elem) > 2:
          elem = f'<a href="/recommendation/?q=%23{elem[1:]}&submit=Search">{elem}</a>'
      res += elem
      sep_index = i * 2 + 1
      if sep_index < len(parts):
          res += parts[sep_index]
return res
```

If a capture group is specified in `re.split`, then the separator is returned too (which is convenient here).

and in your template:

```
<p>{{ text|striptags|mention|linebreaksbr }}</p>
```

`linebreaksbr` only do that, replace `\n` by `<br>`, without wrapping the result in a `p` tag (as you already do it anyway).

If you define text as `text='this is a\n#django \n#test'` and

```py
linebreaksbr(mention(striptags(text)))
```

is invoked, you got

`'this is a<br><a href="/recommendation/?q=%23django&submit=Search">#django</a> <br><a href="/recommendation/?q=%23test&submit=Search">#test</a>'`

Comment: i am not able to test it  because i am getting an error "string index out of range" in "if elem[0] == '#' and len(elem) > 2"

Comment: the filter that i wrote when i tried something like "This is bruxelles \n#iloveyoubruxelles" then i am getting "This is bruxelles <a href="/recommendation/?q=%23iloveyoubruxelles&submit=Search">#iloveyoubruxelles</a>" i am not getting the new line as i wrote in form post in my website.i tried everything.

Comment: i use safe at the end so that the user could see the link not the html .something like twitter does with hash tag.

Comment: maybe the problem is the "striptags" ?

Comment: Ok the problem is where there is multiple delimiter in sequence, like ` \n` where you have space and new-line. Then you may have an empty word (the one between ` ` and `\n`). I edit my answer accordingly.

Comment: `safe` is use to tell that the template engine does not need to escape html sequences because the string is html-safe. Without `safe`, the django template engine will escape some sequences, like `<` or `>` to `&lt;` and `&gt;`. So if you don’t use safe, the html will be escaped and you will see the html as text. `striptags` will simply remove any string starting with `<`, a tag and ending with either `/>` or `</TAG_NAME>`.