# I have this error delete() missing 1 required positional argument: 'id' when I click on the delete button

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-urls

when I click on the delete button, I am supposed to make it delete from my database, but instead I got this error: delete() missing 1 required positional argument: 'id' as shown in the picture below:
[image]

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [

        path('', views.login_user, name='login'),
        path('home/', views.home, name='home'),
        path('allstaff/', views.allstaff, name='allstaff'),
        #path('delete_order/<str:pk>/', views.deleteOrder, name="delete_order"),
        path('delete', views.delete, name='delete'),
        path('logout/', views.logout_view, name='logout'),
        path('register/', views.register_view, name='register'),
        path('edit-register/', views.edit_register_view, name='edit_register'),
]
```

views.py

```
def delete(request, id):
    context = {}
    user = get_object_or_404(User, id=id)
    if request.method == "POST":
        user.delete(id)
        return HttpResponseRedirect("/home")
    return render(request, 'delete.html', context)
```

allstaff.py

```
{% extends "home.html" %}
{% block content %}
<style>
table {
    border-collapse:separate;
    border:solid black 1px;
    border-radius:6px;
    -moz-border-radius:6px;
}

td, th {
    border-left:solid black 1px;
    border-top:solid black 1px;
}

th {
    border-top: none;
}

td:first-child, th:first-child {
     border-left: none;
}



</style>

   <div style="padding-left:16px">
     <br>

 <div class="form-block">
     <table>
  <tr>
    <th>Staff Name</th>
      <th>Staff Username</th>
      <th>Email</th>
      <th>Date Joined</th>
      <th>Action</th>
  </tr>
         {% for user in allusername %}
  <tr>
        <td>{{user.first_name}} {{user.last_name}}</td><td>{{user.username}}</td><td>{{user.email}}</td><td>{{user.date_joined}}</td><td><a class="btn btn-sm btn-info" href="{}">Update</a></td><td><a class="btn btn-sm btn-danger" href="/delete">Delete</a></td>

     </tr>

{% endfor %}

</table>
     <br>
     



</div>
   </div>
{% endblock %}
```

What did I miss out? How do I get it to work so that when I click on the delete button, it will auto delete from my database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The URL should include the primary key (or another unique) field to delete this user, so:

```
path('delete/<int:id>/', views.delete, name='delete'),
```

Then in the template, we make a mini-form that will include the `id` of the `User` object to remove:

```
{% for user in allusername %}
…
<td>
    <form action="{% url 'delete' user.id %}" method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger">Delete</button>
    </form>
</td>
…
{% endfor %}
```

Finally in your view you delete the `User` object *without* specifying the id again: you already have the right object since you fetch the `User` with `id=id`:

```
from django.shortcuts import redirect

def delete(request, id):
    user = get_object_or_404(User, id=id)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        user.delete()
        return redirect('home')
    return render(request, 'delete.html')
```

Comment: @willemvanonsem could you please help me with this question:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69149722/linebreaks-not-working-properly-in-djagno

Comment: Hi, I got this error, but this time round is a different error

Comment: the error is this: CSRF verification failed. Request aborted.

Comment: let me take a look at your question

Comment: @Shadowwalker: sorry, I made a mistake, you should add the `{% csrf_token %}`. to the form.

Comment: I never state anything in the forms for the delete

Comment: @Shadowwalker: a form that makes a POST request, normally has a `{% csrf_token %}` to prevent cross-site-request-forgery where a (malicious) script of another host could make a *forged* POST request.

Comment: I see, thanks for your help, now i will take a look at your question and see if I can help you